# PHP, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, continuous-integration

How to loop the data? All image are displaying at one slide other slides are empty.

```
  <div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php foreach($banner as $data) { ?>
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/banner/<?php echo $data['image']?>" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
  </div>
  <?php }?>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/image/c.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
  </div>


</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

How to loop the data? All image are displaying at one slide other slides are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php 
$i = 0;
foreach($banner as $data) { ?>
  <div class="item <?php echo $i==0 ? 'active' : ''; $i++; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/banner/<?php echo $data['image']?>" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
  </div>
  <?php }?> 

</div>
```